# Can i use .NET framework on c++

Tags: .net

I am not sure if I wanna use a different framework or .NET if possible.
Side note: I dabbled in c# .NET but not seriously
i don't wanna use a completely different framework and dont wanna stray too far from regular c++

Comment: Yes, there is C++/CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp

Comment: [Is it possible to use C++ with the .NET framework?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/135083/73708)